# BlockCypher signing Bitcoin transaction incorrect private key format

Tags: php, bitcoin

I am trying to sign a Bitcoin transaction using the [BlockCypher API](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/) but I am failing because I don't have my private key in the correct format.

According to their documentation:

"One of the most common errors in the signing process is a data format mismatch. We always return and expect hex-encoded data, but oftentimes, standard signing libraries require byte arrays. Remember to convert your data, and always send hex-encoded signatures to BlockCypher."

The PHP code should be as follows:

```
$privateKeys = array("2c2cc015519b79782bd9c5af66f568e808f573714f3c4dc6df7d79c183783cff");
$txSkeleton = $txClient->sign($txSkeleton, $privateKeys);
```

But my private key is in the format `xprv9s21ZrQH143K4NejhhRcspQdS2g7JgnSVwmT2dkXQuszJaQqjYD3wdUdsXyqmfetdUZ2SS25uM7nAfnUwNDGA75bfqYxKwYZ8zDdaCv6meL`, ie not in hex.

I have tried simply converting it to hex, which obviously was a bit overoptimistic of me but the transaction signing fails.

I have thoroughly web-searched this and have been unable to figure out how to convert a `xprv` prefix key into the correct format as required by the BlockCypher API.

I am a paying customer of theirs and have e-mailed them but no reply after two weeks of waiting.

Comment: If you've been waiting for two weeks for a reply from company you pay money to, is it time to swap to a different provider?

Comment: @Markus Did the blockcypher support finally respond? Were you able to solve your transaction signing issue? Please share updates.